# Zombie.js and scripts that write to window

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, zombie.js

I'm having some trouble with `Zombie.js` and evaluating scripts which write stuff to the `window` variable. Here is an example to show what I mean:

Say I have a script `foo.js` which does the following:

`window.foo = 'foo';`

Then I visit the following html page (which includes `foo.js`) using zombie.js:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>
 <head>
   <title>zombiejs test </title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      console.log(window.foo);
    </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I would have assumed that the `window.foo` variable would be available for the rest of the page after the execution of foo.js, but it seems this is not the case as running:

`Browser.visit('http://localhost:8087/test.html')`

gives me `undefined`.

Is there any particular reason this happens or am I doing something wrong here? Does Zombie.js evaluate the scripts into a different context which is not the same context where the page is run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't totally make sense to me, but I'll give it a shot. Have you tried running this in a normal browser and seeing if it works there? If it does, it might be a bug in zombie.js, which you should file in [its github issues](https://github.com/assaf/zombie/issues).

Browsing through the issues briefly, I saw a few already open that are related to the window object, it might be worth looking through these. For example, https://github.com/assaf/zombie/pull/360.

That being said, although I don't have a direct answer to this question, I have two suggestions that might get you through the problem.

- Use a document ready handler in your on-page script and a callable function in your external script. So in foo.js, it would look like this:

  window.foo_value = function(){ return 'foo' };

and in your on-page script, like this

```
<script>
  window.onload(function(){ console.log(window.foo_value) });
</script>
```

... no guarantees that this would work, but if it didn't it would definitely be a bug in zombie.js, and you could file that as an issue and hopefully get it fixed.

- Use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), which does the same thing and is more popular : )